# Create template prompt one time from LangChain / OpenAi to reduce tokens

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

I am using LangChain and OpenAi to query a SQL Server database. I am exceeding the token limits because LangChain prompts the model (which is `gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613`)

```
You are an MS SQL expert. Given an input question, first create a syntactically correct MS SQL query to run, then look at the results of the query and return the answer to the input question.
Unless the user specifies in the question a specific number of examples to obtain, query for at most {top_k} results using the TOP clause as per MS SQL. You can order the results to return the most informative data in the database.
Never query for all columns from a table. You must query only the columns that are needed to answer the question. Wrap each column name in square brackets ([]) to denote them as delimited identifiers.
Pay attention to use only the column names you can see in the tables below. Be careful to not query for columns that do not exist. Also, pay attention to which column is in which table.

Use the following format:

Question: "Question here"
SQLQuery: "SQL Query to run"
SQLResult: "Result of the SQLQuery"
Answer: "Final answer here"

Only use the following tables:
{table_info}

Question: {input}
```

for every query. Is there a way to do this ***once*** to reduce the amount of tokens and fit the actual query in? I was looking at different ideas such as [Memory](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/memory.html) and [finetuning](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/preparing-your-dataset) the model.
This is my code that works on small DBs and small tables but once I test it with a real DB with many tables and columns I run into token limits. I assume that the `table_info` variable is taking up most of the tokens. This is what I have so far.

```
import openai
from langchain import SQLDatabaseChain
from langchain.sql_database import SQLDatabase
from langchain.llms.openai import OpenAI
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

def connect_to_DB():
    driver = '{SQL Server}'
    server = 'MyServer'
    database = 'NorthWind'

    # pyodbc connection string
    connection_string = f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};'
    connection_string += f'DATABASE={database};'

    connection_url = URL.create(
        "mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})
    db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(connection_url, engine_args={"use_setinputsizes":False})

    return db

if __name__ == '__main__':

    OPENAI_API_KEY = 'OPENAI_API_KEY'
    engine = connect_to_DB()
    llm = OpenAI(temperature=0, verbose=False, openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613')
    db_chain = SQLDatabaseChain.from_llm(llm, engine, verbose=True, return_intermediate_steps=True)
    while True:
        query = input()
        print(query)
        try:
            result = db_chain(query)
            result["intermediate_steps"]
        except openai.error.InvalidRequestError:
            continue
```

Comment: Short answer is no and the reason is that openai apis are stateless.  They have no knowledge of what went before therefore they must be told each time (aka request). Hope this helps though I'm not sure how.

Comment: Ok thanks. Then Memory is just a way to save and inject into the request?

Comment: Basically - yes. There are ways to inject only the relevent memories but as far as I know, a solution like that needs to be coded from scratch.  If you think about vector similarity search but limited to conversation memory then you are headed in the right direction.